# de referencing a structure variable in C

Tags: c, structure, operator-precedence

I have two structures like this

```
typedef struct foo_ {
int id;
int var1;
int var2; 
} foo_t;

typedef struct bar_ {
int member1;
int member2;
foo_t an_array[10]; 
} bar_t;
```

I have a pointer to the structure `bar_` as `bar_t *ptr`

Now i need to access the `id` in `foo`

I get it as `ptr->an_array[index].id`
Since it is an integer, there won't be any problem.
But how do I pass the the variable `id` by reference?

`&ptr->an_array[index].id` doesn't seem to work
nor does `&ptr->(an_array[index].id)`

I went through the precedences but still can't get it working.

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: `some_other_struct_p an_array[10];` should be `some_other_struct_t an_array[10];` i guess.

Comment: yeah that was a typo @SouravGhosh

Comment: @AnuragKakati: Moral: For example code in questions, don't use extremely long and hard to read names. Prefer short names like `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: `&ptr->an_array[index].id ` works just fine?

Answer (score 1):

Check your code again - `&ptr->an_array[index].id` should work just fine. Postfix operators (`->`, `[]`, `.`) bind tighter than `&`, so there should be no problem. Maybe there is another issue in your original code?